# How to specify fn in DefaultKeyBinding.dict?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I've found many pages indicating that <kbd>fn</kbd> can't be remapped because it never gets sent to the OS (eg https://super-unix.com/askdifferent/macos-mapping-usb-keyboard-fn-key-to-option-key-with-defaultkeybinding-dict/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-code/#function-section). But Mac allows using <kbd>fn</kbd> to switch input sources and Karabiner EventViewer shows when <kbd>fn</kbd> is pressed.

What is the code that can be used in `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` to detect a <kbd>fn</kbd> press?

Comment: can you link to some of those pages in your question?